# How do I create files when all I have is an uri of a directory? (Persistable permission for the directory was granted by the Android user.)

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, file-permissions

I am trying to write and read files that are also visible and editable from a PC when the android device is connected to it via USB. These files might be created through the PC connection.

To achieve this I'm trying to take a persistable URI permission to a directory, and then create or read the files in that directory.

I am in the "proof of concept" phase.

Inside the MainActivity OnCreate method I have the following code:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
}, GET_PERSISTABLE_PERMISSION)
```

When I start te app, the directory picker pops up and I'm able to select a directory.

In MainActivity I also have:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == GET_PERSISTABLE_PERMISSION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val uri = data?.data!!
        val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)

        val tmpFile = File(uri.path, "debugTestFile.txt")
        tmpFile.createNewFile()
        tmpFile.appendText("árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép\r\n")
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Things I've tried:

- `uri.toString()` instead of `uri.path`
- `flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` when creating the intent
- giving different directories on the Android device in the Downloads, Music, DCIM folders, when prompted by Android

Despite my best efforts, the `tmpFile.createNewFile()` line throws an exception with "No such file or directory" message.

```
    Process: hu.ibcs.android.scan, PID: 17309
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:Music/GVtest flg=0xc3 }} to activity {hu.ibcs.android.scan/hu.ibcs.android.scan.MainActivity}: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4846)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4887)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at hu.ibcs.android.scan.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:106)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4839)
```

Comment: `apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION`That does not make sense as you cannot grant anything as you are not the provider. Please remove. Instead you should be glad that in onActivityResult you get an uri and are granted permissions which you can take persistent. Well you are doing that.

Comment: `val tmpFile = File(uri.path, "debugTestFile.txt")` That is nonsense as uri.path is not a file system path and you cannot use the File class for it. Instead you should use a DocumentFile variable for the obtained uri and use SAF or Storage Access Framework methods to create folders and files.

Comment: `How do I use a persistable permission that was granted by the Android user?` You mean: `How do I use an uri of a file seleced by the Android user?`

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the help!
The uri is of a directory not a file. I'm trying to get access to an entire directory and create/read multiple different files in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @blackapps for the suggestions!

I changed the code in MainActivity.onCreate to:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), GET_PERSISTABLE_PERMISSION)
```

and the code in MainActivity to:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == GET_PERSISTABLE_PERMISSION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val uri = data?.data!!
        val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)

        val pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri)
        val tmpFile = pickedDir.createFile("text/csv", "debugTestFile")
        val out: OutputStream? = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(tmpFile!!.uri)
        out?.write(("\uFEFF" + "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép\r\n").toByteArray()) // adding BOM to the start for Excel to recognize utf8
        out?.close()
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

It's working and it looks like I can move on from here.